# Get the length of the string in substitution

Tags: vim

I'd like to calculate the length of a replace string used in a substitution. That is, "bar" in `:s/foo/bar`. Suppose I have access to this command string, I can run and undo it, and may separate the parts marked by `/` with split(). How would I get the string length of the replace string if it contains special characters like \1, \2 etc or ~?

For instance if I have

```
:s/\v(foo)|(bars)/\2\rreplace/
```

the replace length would be strlen("bars\rreplace") = 12.

EDIT: Just to be clear, I hope to use this to move the cursor past the text that was affected by a substitute operation. I'd appreciate alternative solutions as well.

Comment: What do you want to do with the length? Include it in the replacement, store it in a variable, ???

Comment: @Ingo Karkat; I'd like to store it into a variable. This is so that I could move the cursor past the part of the buffer that was changed by :s. Of course I wouldn't mind alternative solutions if any exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `:help sub-replace-expression`. In it, you use `submatch(2)` instead of `\2`. If the expression is a custom function, you can as a side effect store the original length in a variable, and access that later:

```
function! Replace()
    let g:replaceLength = strlen(submatch(0))
    " Equivalent of \2\rreplace
    return submatch(2) . "\r" . 'replace'
endfunction

:s/\v(foo)|(bars)/\=Replace()/
```